# Javascript Dropzone allowing folder upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload, frontend, dropzone

I am currently trying to create a dropzone file uploader that can also accept folders, and upload the files by recursively traverse the folder.
Here is my implementation so far, my goal is to make one request in order to reduce the traffic :

```js
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hideDropZone();
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    uploadFiles(items);
});

function uploadFiles(items) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var entry = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (entry.isFile) {
          entry.file(function(file) {
            formData.append("files", file, file.webkitRelativePath+file.name);
          });
        }
      }
    
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/u?d='+get('d')); 

    request.send(formData);

}
```

With this implementation, when I check the content of the form, it seems that it is empty.
How can I perform the upload so that the form is not empty when I upload files/folders ?
Thanks by advance for your help !

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited, sorry for that. I d'ont understand why my formData stays empty while I am populating it